# Ubuntu 14.04 BIOS skipping and cannot change display settings

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia

I just started having a couple of problems with Ubuntu that occurred at the same time, which makes me thing they are related. I dual boot into Ubuntu and Windows and all of a sudden my BIOS screen stopped appearing and it booted directly into Ubuntu. Also, the dual screen settings, which had been unchanged for months, suddenly reset and I cannot change them back. When I open Display I cannot select the other screen, clicking on it simply does nothing. Also, just a moment ago I tried to boot it up and only got a black screen. After restarting it it booted directly into Ubuntu again. Are these all connected? I'm wondering if there's a problem with my NVIDIA graphics card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they were all connected. I disabled Fast Boot and it solved everything.